# Dropbox install in VirtualBox Xubuntu

Tags: linux, virtualbox, dropbox, xubuntu

I'm a Linux newbie that's having a fair bit of trouble getting Dropbox to run in Xubuntu 13.10 (which is in VirtualBox – Windows 8.1 host).

Everything seems to install correctly, but when it starts for the first time, nothing happens. I don't get a 'Dropbox Setup' window to enter my account. The Dropbox status is perpetually `Connecting...` I do see a taskbar icon, but when I go into Dropbox preferences, everything is greyed out. The `.dropbox` folder is made in my home directory, but not the `Dropbox` folder.

I've tried uninstalling it and reinstalling in several different ways, but it's always the same. I'm not sure if the problem lies with Dropbox, Xubuntu or VirtualBox. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I went to try user1201232's suggestion of looking at the log before/after installation, and it miraculously worked this time!  I have absolutely no idea what's changed and why it worked now and not before, but whatever - I'm content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install Dropbox? from the Xubuntu repository? or do you download it from `dropbox.com`? have you tried another (beta, or older) version of Dropbox?

Have you had a look in the syslog?

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

(Do this before you try to install/run Dropbox, so you can see anything that happens there.)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer not because it fixed the problem - my issue just mysteriously went away on its own.  Rather, this taught me a new Linux approach to troubleshooting, so I'm grateful.

Comment: glad I could help with something